# Link em imagem em html

Tags: html

Ola eu queria colocar um link na imagem, para quando alguem clicar ser redirecionado para o endereço x

```
<div class="locais-destaque">
<div class="container">
  <div class="content-locais">
    <h4>Melhores Lugares</h4>

    <div class="row01-locais">
      <div class="col-locais">
          <img src="images/local.png">
          <p>Pedra da Macela, SP</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite. Tudo bem?

Para colocar um link dentro de uma imagem basta você colocá-la dentro de uma tag de hiperlink, a tag "a"

Ficaria dessa forma:

**`<a href = "https://linkQueVoceQuiser.csb"><img src = "images/local.png" </a>`**

*Espero de algum forma ter te ajudado. Bons estudos!*

Answer (score -2):

O elemento `<a>` em HTML (ou elemento âncora), com o atributo hrefcria-se uma hiperligação nas páginas web, arquivos, endereços de emails, links na mesma página ou endereços na URL. O conteúdo dentro de cada `<a>` precisará indicar o destino do link.

Para se criar uma imagem com um link, o seguinte modelo de código deverá ser usado:

```
<a href = "https://linkpraondefordirecionar.com"><img src = "imagens/linkdaimagem.jpg" </a>
```

Comment: Faltou fechar a tag ```img```